# User Authentication in react application uses the server side rendering without using flux

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-router, server-side-rendering

Is anyone suggest me how to implement the user authentication in simple react application which using the server side rendering.
I have try to use the localstorage to save and retrieve the value.
And usign the condition like,
`{ If Auth.loggedIn() ? "Hello" : "Hi"}` somewhere in the code I got the error.

"Uncaught Invariant Violation: You're trying to render a component to the document using server rendering but the checksum was invalid. This usually means you rendered a..."

I debug and find out the issue with localstorage the component is render at server and client side both, at client side it gets the value Auth.loggedIn() true and server side is false so the component is mismatching thats why causing the error.

I google but couldn't find any good solution to fix the error.

Is anyone suggest how to fix the problem?
[image]

Comment: Can you not use cookies?

Comment: You shouldn't use localStorage for storing session information because that is accessible from any application. With cookies you can easily read the request cookies on the server and prepare your components so that the server and the client rendered code match

Comment: Thanks man it works :)